# "ongoing" vs "enduring"

Tags: word-meaning

I encountered the sentence

> 'An **ongoing** debate is whether a high amount of energy raises a nation
>   or region's gross national product (GNP) or whether rising GNP
>   increases the consumption of energy.'

Can I replace ***'ongoing'*** with ***'enduring***' yet without giving rise to any different meaning?
I feel that the difference between *ongoing* and *enduring* involves the present moment. Is my understanding right?

By the way, could the word ***'durative'*** be also used as an adjective here?  (in the meaning *'ongoing'* or *'enduring'* beyond its nominal use)

Comment: Did you check the dictionary definitions? You should add them to your question, and if unclear, in what way?

Comment: I had not come across the word 'durative' before I read your question - it is not something I have ever read or heard used in conversation, though I did look it up in the dictionary and found its definition. Thanks for the vocab, not sure it would help you to understand the distinction between ongoing and enduring however.

Answer (score 2):

In the quote the usage of ongoing seems descriptive - if you replaced it with enduring I think the difference is that it is more forceful.

Enduring is more forceful in terms of describing the debate as being a long-standing debate that has been "ongoing" for a long time, and adds the connotation that it is a debate that is and remains hard to resolve.

There is a slight difference in the time period people would assume for each word, but this can depend on usage:

**Ongoing:** implies that the debate has occurred in the past, is continuing and will happen in the future. I think this is more about ongoing's usage in general. There is something about ongoing that feels and implies that things are happening in the present, more so than enduring.

**Enduring:** implies that the debate has occurred in the past and is continuing. Does not seem to me to give as much a sense of the debate presently occurring.

I would even go so far as to say that enduring could add the connotation that the debate is old, tired, maybe even troubling, as well as hard to resolve - this connotation would only be there if enduring was used in conversation and said in an annoyed or tired tone of voice.

Another way to tease out the distinction between ongoing and enduring might be to think about when police are being interviewed about a criminal investigation by journalists, and they  are asked a question they cannot/will not answer. They tend to say:

> "Our investigation is ongoing."

This makes it sound like they are doing something right now (which makes them sound good, effective, etc...) and is a nice way to get out of answering the question.

Not:

> "The investigation is enduring."

This is an odd usage of the word enduring, but if it were said, people would assume that there are difficulties with the investigation, and that it is ongoing despite difficulties.

Hope that answers your question or gives you some perspective on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I replace 'ongoing' with 'enduring' yet without giving rise to any different meaning?

You will change the connotation of the phrase by making that change.  'Endure' is too loaded for that change to be non-impactful.

Looking up the words as adjectives, they have very similar meaning.

But 'enduring' also has common use as the verb 'endure'.

'Endure' almost always implies something bad, or negative, is happening.

- People endure torture.
- Mountains manage to endure, despite eons of erosion.
- Employees endure their boss's bad jokes.
- Dogs endure loneliness while their owners are at work.